# Font Awesome Icons generated with Javascript not showing unless I refresh page

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, font-awesome, turbolinks

My font awesome icons work properly through my entire application if they are inserted directly in my HTML code like this:

```
<div>
  <i class="fas fa-address-book"></i>
</div>
```

But when I add them dynamically with Javascript they do not appear unless I refresh the page.
For example, this won't work unless I refresh the page:

```
for (i=0; i < fields_number; i++){
  var weight_field = document.createElement('div');
  weight_field.innerHTML = ('<i class="fas fa-address-book"></i>')
  container.appendChild(weight_field);
}
```

How can I make the icons show up without having to refresh ?

Update:
It's a rails 5 application that uses turbolinks.

and I am adding font awesome using CDN the following way:

```
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-8iPTk2s/jMVj81dnzb/iFR2sdA7u06vHJyyLlAd4snFpCl/SnyUjRrbdJsw1pGIl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Should `class="fas ..."` be `class="fa ..."` or does `fas` have special meaning? I haven't seen that before.

Comment: @wbadart That's just the HTML code provided by font awesome in their documentation.

Comment: Which version of fontawesome are you using? Your code works for me on version 4 ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wysgvz7f/))

Comment: @SebastianDelgado FA has `fas` in v5 now instead of `fa`.

Comment: please provide more code. Your code works for me on version 5 [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smollet92/f5y3cozb/)

Comment: I added more information related to my application, but there isn't more code related to that functionality, thanks a lot for reading !

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by replacing the CDN that I used, which was a script that form some reason was conflicting with turbo-links with a stylesheet.

PROBLEMATIC:

```
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-8iPTk2s/jMVj81dnzb/iFR2sdA7u06vHJyyLlAd4snFpCl/SnyUjRrbdJsw1pGIl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

WORKING WITH TURBOLINKS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
```